# How to pass build parameters and other information to powershell script in TFS2013 build?

Tags: powershell, tfs, build

I am using default build template with TFS 2013, how i can access build parameters (for example, changeset number under build, build directory, source paths, tfs address, agent information...) from powershell script?

Example situation: I want to rewrite all assembly info version informations on Pre-Build script where last part of version number is changeset number, i can probably get changeset with tf.exe commands inside of script but i isn't only thing which i want to know from build agent during build.

I have tried run Get-Variable in script and write it to build but i haven't find any special variables inside of script.

Is there something i have missed or is it so that default build template simply does not pass any variables to powershell runtime during execution?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Figured it out.

Variables are automatically written as environment variables, dir env: showed me that tfs automatically create following variables:

```
 TF_BUILD                       True
 TF_BUILD_BINARIESDIRECTORY     C:\WP0\101\bin
 TF_BUILD_BUILDDEFINITIONNAME   TfsBuildTest2
 TF_BUILD_BUILDDIRECTORY        C:\WP0\101
 TF_BUILD_BUILDNUMBER           TfsBuildTest2_20140310.3
 TF_BUILD_BUILDREASON           Manual
 TF_BUILD_BUILDURI              vstfs:///Build/Build/6521
 TF_BUILD_DROPLOCATION
 TF_BUILD_SOURCEGETVERSION      C22404
 TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY      C:\WP0\101\src
 TF_BUILD_TESTRESULTSDIRECTORY  C:\WP0\101\tst
 TFS_REG_CRED                   Build
```

Comment: For what it's worth, these are documented here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850448.aspx  +1 for discovering TFS_REG_CRED, which isn't documented.

Comment: How did you actually declare these in your powershell script? Or did you pass them in as parameters from the build definition? e.g. for example $("TF_BUILD") or just TF_Build?

Comment: These are environment variables. In Powershell the syntax is $env:TF_BUILD_BUILDNUMBER

Comment: What if you create a new (custom) variable in the build template (like versionnumber for incrementing assemblyInfo.cls)  how can you get that variable in the powershell script?

Comment: For the life of me I always get empty string for TF_BUILD_BUILDURI. I've created a variable and still nothing